# dealing with zero log values in numpy/pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas that stores a column containing ratios. The ratios need to be transformed into a `log2` scale for plotting but the ratio values are often 0, leading in `log2(0)` which is recorded as `inf` or a missing value in pandas. I want to visualize these since in my dataframe a ratio value of 0 is meaningful. What is the best way to deal with this in pandas/numpy? When I take the log values, is the preferred way to do this?

```
# take log with tiny value added
c = 0.0000001
df[col].apply(lamda x: log2(c + x))
```

or are there other ways? thanks.

Comment: This is equivalent to just replacing your `inf`s with a completely arbitrary number `log2(.0000001)`  Why don't you just remove the `inf`s when you plot and leave the `0`s when not plotting?

Comment: Assuming your ratios are positive, if you take `c = 1.0` then `log2(c + x)` will map [0,inf) --> [0,inf).

Comment: @askewchan: because I want to plot the 0s too. They make up a substantial part of the data.

Comment: If you want to plot `0` in a log plot (which should be at $\infty$, you could consider the `pyplot.symlog` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can use `numpy.inf` to identify those that are `infinity` and treat them separately.

Ref: [github.com/pydata/pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2858)